# What means "mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/man2/setitimer.2.gz: ungültige symbolische Verknüpfung oder »roff«-».so«-Anfrage"

Tags: fedora-25

I wrote a local manpage.

In the end, install procedure for local manpage in folder manl/ is successful, I do a test by

```
mandb --test
```

Output is

```
[mef@furie 0.9]$ sudo mandb --test
mandb: /usr/share/man/man2/getitimer.2 kann nicht geöffnet werden: No such file or directory
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/man2/setitimer.2.gz: ungültige symbolische Verknüpfung oder »roff«-».so«-Anfrage
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/man1/mprof-report.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für mprof-report(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/man3/function::-.3stap.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für function::-(3stap) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/man3/function::MKDEF.3stap.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für function::MKDEF(3stap) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/man3/function::sa_handler.3stap.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für function::sa_handler(3stap) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/man3/probe::sunrpc.svc.authorise.3stap.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für probe::sunrpc.svc.authorise(3stap) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/zh_TW/man1/dcraw.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für dcraw(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/zh_TW/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/id/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/hr/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/free.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für free(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/pgrep.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für pgrep(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/dos2unix.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für dos2unix(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/dos2unix.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für unix2dos(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/dos2unix.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für unix2mac(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/dos2unix.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für mac2unix(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/pidof.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für pidof(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/pgrep.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für pkill(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/pmap.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für pmap(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/pwdx.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für pwdx(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/skill.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für skill(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/slabtop.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für slabtop(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/tload.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für tload(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/uptime.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für uptime(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/w.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für w(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man1/watch.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für watch(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man5/sysctl.conf.5.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für sysctl.conf(5) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man8/sysctl.8.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für sysctl(8) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/uk/man8/vmstat.8.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für vmstat(8) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/uk/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/da/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/nl/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: /usr/share/man/pl/man1/pgrep.1 kann nicht geöffnet werden: No such file or directory
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/pl/man1/pkill.1.gz: ungültige symbolische Verknüpfung oder »roff«-».so«-Anfrage
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/pl/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/ja/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/es/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/zh/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/pt/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/pt_PT/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/zh_CN/man1/dcraw.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für dcraw(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/zh_CN/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/hu/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/de/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/pt_BR/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/ko/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/sk/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/cs/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/it/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/fr/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/ca/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/eo/man1/dcraw.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für dcraw(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/eo/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/sv/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: /usr/share/man/ro/man1/dcraw.1.gz: whatis-Verarbeitung für dcraw(1) fehlgeschlagen
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/ro/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/tr/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/ru/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable
mandb: Warnung: Indexcache /var/cache/man/local/index.db kann nicht aktualisiert werden: Resource temporarily unavailable

[mef@furie 0.9]$ uname -a
Linux furie.our-domain.top-level 4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 12:36:38 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[mef@furie 0.9]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="25 (Workstation Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=25
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 25 (Workstation Edition)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:25"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=25
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=25
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL=https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy
VARIANT="Workstation Edition"
VARIANT_ID=workstation
```

What [is | did I] wrong?

Comment: Would this question be better on [linux.se]?

Comment: It says "No such file or directory", where does the path `/usr/share/man/man2/getitimer.2` comes from? As for the rest of the output, I'm unfortunately not fluent in german...

Comment: There is a thread at: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1334279

Comment: @Andrew Myers you're alright!